# Why this won't fetch source code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This code should fetch the HTML source of `http://yahoo.com/(index.html)`, and show it in dialog.

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://yahoo.com', success: function(data) {
    alert(data); 
    } 
});
```

However, it won't do anything...

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Same Origin Policy !!!!

Comment: Because you cannot make Ajax calls to external domains unless they **explicitly** allow it (google CORS). Most "normal" websites (not web APIs) don't.

Comment: Try looking at your browser's developer tools for the error.

Comment: *"This code should fetch the HTML source of http://yahoo.com/(index.html), and show it in dialog."* No, it shouldn't. It should throw a very obvious and descriptive error in your javascript console.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for your explanation.  So is CURL the only way to fetch external website's HTML source?

Comment: @Paulpro No. I just put yahoo as an example. What I wanted to know is what FelixKling said.  It seems impossible to fetch HTML source code of external websites

Comment: Just write a PHP (or ASP whatever) on your server, get the content, and call your script in the AJAXcall..

Comment: @reyaner Thanks. I concerned about that way before. But if my program on the server accesses to particular website to fetch HTML for more than 10,000 times a day, the owner of website will add IP address of my server to their block list, right? That's why I wanted clients PCs to take a part for it.

Comment: @cat if it's being fetched that many times, you can have your server cache the response so that it only requests, for example, once per hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, you're not allowed to make cross domain requests. This violate the Cross Origin policy.

To make it work the requested domain must emit headers that allow the requesting domain.

I've got a tutorial on how to set and use the CORS policy: http://fritsvancampen.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/cross-site-origin-requests-aka-cross-origin-resource-sharing/
but if you want to fetch data from Yahoo you need control over their domain .. and that's not gonna happen ;)

Comment: Also a nice resource (I think, I never actually had to use CORS): http://enable-cors.org/.

Comment: That resource doesn't cover the nuances. `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` is just lazy and sloppy.

Comment: Thanks for the advices guys! So what do you guys think would be the best to fetch external website's HTML code? Just like google crawler.  Setting up CURL for it?

Comment: I see. Well, it's a GitHub project, so you can suggest improvements ;)

Comment: @FelixKling If you were me, how would you fetch external website's HTML source? on PHP or Ruby? But I'm afraid of being added to blocklist because of the exceeded accesses from my server.

Comment: @cat: I mostly used Python for this kind of scripting (I don't know Ruby and I find Python more powerful than PHP). To become blocked is a valid concern and there is no silver bullet solution for this. I didn't get into troubles because apparently I didn't make too many requests. If the website offers an API to access the data, you should rather use it.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you very much:) Now, all my troubles are gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is not used for your purpose . you have to used like this

```
   $content = file_get_contents('http://www.yahoo.com/');
    print_r($content);
```

Or this could be helpful for you 
http://toolspot.org/extract-website-data.php